# Stackoverflow alignment error

Tags: bug, design, editor, uploader

Is it mistake by stackoverflow or there is bug in my browser

1.

[image]

2.

[image]

Comment: What's your browser?

Comment: mozilla firefox

Comment: Version? And are you at the default zoom level?

Comment: yes its on default

Comment: It looks like you've resized your browser with the modal displayed. It seems that the image upload modal is not responsive to browser resizes.

Comment: What are we supposed to be looking at exactly? Is it the modal dialog?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The "Insert an image" modal dialog appears to not be responsive when it comes to browser resizing. Here's a screenshot from Chrome:

[image]

The "Insert hyperlink" modal does respond to resizes though. It stays centered (both vertically and horizontally):

[image]

So I would guess that this is a bug with the "Insert an image" dialog.

The reason for this is the CSS applied to the image dialog:

```
<div style="display: block; 
            padding: 10px; 
            width: 400px;
            z-index: 1001; 
            position: absolute; 
            top: 313.5px; 
            left: 494px; " 
     class="wmd-prompt-dialog">
</div>
```

Compared to that of the link dialog:

```
<div class="wmd-prompt-dialog" 
     style="position: fixed; 
            width: 400px; 
            z-index: 1001; 
            top: 50%; 
            left: 50%; 
            display: block; 
            margin-top: -71px; 
            margin-left: -203px; ">
</div>
```

You can see that the link dialog is positioned with percentages, and the image dialog is positioned with pixel values, causing it to stay where it is when you resize the browser window.